# Can I rely on non-chained subsequent promises order?

Tags: javascript, promise

It is known one can combine multiple Promises into a chain and thereby call `onFulfilled` callbacks exactly one by one (despite they will be asynchronous from each other):

```
Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
       console.log("i will be the first one");     
    })
    .then(() => {
       console.log("i will be the second one");  // definetely second
    })
;
```

But what about non-chained subsequent Promises? 
The simplest example:

```
Promise.resolve()
   .then(() => console.log("i will be the first one"))
;
Promise.resolve()
   .then(() => console.log("i will be the second one"))  // sure?
;
```

In my naive opinion, Promises callbacks works via event queue (about like timer event inside `setTimeout`) and in that way first `Promise.resolve()` push its event in queue before second one do this, therefore first callback will be called before second one.

But I am not sure there are any guarantees about it. Can I rely on it or it is an async lotto? Does someone know what specs tell about it?

**UPDATE**

Some of you noticed is the simplest example is useless so I want to explain my original problem.

I have a class which lazy initializes instance of another class and provides get method for the hosted instance:

```
class Lazy {

    /** @param {Class} T */
    constructor(T) { }

    /** @returns {Promise.<T>} */
    instance() { 
       // there will be complex async initialization at first call
       // and Promise.resolve() at following calls
    }
}

class Foo {
   on() { }
   off() { }
}

/** @type {Lazy.<Foo>} */
let foo = new Lazy(Foo);

foo.instance().then((i) => i.on());
foo.instance().then((i) => i.off());
```

Last two lines reveal my problem - it is difficult to work with`Foo` instance in that way when I am not sure that `on()` will be called before `off()`.

Comment: This may be of help to you https://promisesaplus.com

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems like you're trying to get rid of the purpose of promises, i.e., allowing asynchronous responses. If you're trying to get `setTimeout(..., 0)`-like behavior, use `setTimeout`. If you want to guarantee order, use `async`-`await`. If you have instantly-returning synchronous events, don't use Promises.

Comment: `sure?` - yes, you can be sure

Comment: have you also considered `const p = Promise.resolve(); p.then(() => console.log("i will be the first one")); p.then(() => console.log("i will be the second one"));`

Comment: This whole question is pretty much unimportant because if you don't have actual async operations, then don't use promises in the first place.  If you do have async operations, then the finish order is always indeterminate (unless the underlying two operations are somehow related to each other).  So, who cares whether two `Promise.resolve()` calls are served in order or not.  It should never matter in your code.  If it does, code differently to guarantee the order!

Comment: For understanding how this stuff works, the event queue is FIFO for events of the exact same type (there are several sub-queues with different priorities for different types of events).  But, for the exact same event (a promise resolving), events will be processed in the order they were put in the queue.  I'm not sure this is required by specification, but it is how they generally work.  I still don't think you should ever assume an order like you've asked about.  If your code cares, then code it to define the execution order in your code.

Comment: @JaromandaX I thought about it. Again it is "clear" that callback in first `then` will be call firstly, but I do not know any guarantees about it. Why cannot first `then` slow down from second one with pushing event in queue?

Comment: @JonathanLam I have updated my post by more meaningful example.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated my post by more meaningful example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your actual issue:

> Last two lines reveal my problem - it is difficult to work withFoo instance in that way when I am not sure that on() will be called before off().

You should not rely on this behaviour, instead you should `await` for obtaining the instance and then cache it:

```
async function withInstance() {
  let instance = await foo.instance();    
  await instance.on();
  await instance.off(); // guaranteed to be called after `.on`.
}
```

#### What you asked

You can rely on execution order of `Job`s.

When a promise `then` is added it's an [`EnqueueJob`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-enqueuejob) in the spec. Quoting [Jobs and Job Queues](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues):

> The PendingJob records from a single Job Queue are always initiated in FIFO order.

Note this guarantee does not hold if you have multiple contexts (for example - different promises between iframes or workers).

That said - it is highly not recommended to rely on the execution order like that.

Answer (score 1):

> Promises callbacks works via event queue

This isn't true. Callbacks work on a first returned first served basis. The ordering of when you initiate the operation is unimportant, it's the order that they **return** that decides which operation will be processed first.

In your example if your "first" async operation takes longer to return than your "second" async operation then the "second" `then` will be processed first.

Obviously there are lots of variables on how long these operation will take to return. Network speed, load on the server (or whatever async service your using), the browsers implementation of the promise engine, etc. etc. So **you have to assume that you have no idea when these will be processed**.

To avoid race conditions if you need something to be in a specific order then use callbacks/`.then`/`await`/etc to ensure that they run in that order. You cannot rely on the order that you call the operation.

Comment: "you have no idea when these will be processed." - actually, you do and it's guaranteed by the language specification. Doesn't make it a good idea to rely on it though.

Comment: I've extended my bold, the whole sentence is *you have to **assume** that you have no idea when these will be processed.* :) @BenjaminGruenbaum